# Getting a value from a function for a $scope variable

Tags: angularjs, function, mean-stack

i am using angularJS.. and i dont know if global variable works on it. i have a value from a function that i would like to save to a $scope variable. Here is my code:

```
$scope.currentPositionLat='';


// center to the geoIP
$window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
       $scope.currentPositionLat = position.coords.latitude;
        Locations.reverseGeoCode(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude).then(function(loc){
            //$scope.loc = loc;
            console.log(position.coords.latitude);
            console.log(loc);



        });

    }, function(error) {
       // alert(error);
    });

console.log('position' + $scope.currentPositionLat);
```

The variable $scope.currentPositionLat is returning blank. ( i guess because i declare it blank). How can i make it get the value inside the function?

Comment: you can create a `.value('Location', Locations)` and then inject that into controllers if you want to bring outside libraries into the angular world

Comment: so you are trying to update an angular variable by using a JQuery function? what is this `position` parameter that is being passed in?  and when is this function being called?

Comment: @Claies there is no jquery

Comment: It seems I'm confused.  I've never seen this `$window.navigator` pattern used before, I'm not really sure what it's supposed to be doing.

Comment: That part is to get the geo ip of the user

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have a scope variable be global please use $rootScope.

You can give the variable a name like for instance $rootScope.username and then call it back in any controller you need it.

Remember that global variables come with a big warning. You should be sure u need to use one before you implement it.